# Create new Object by string variable in Symfony3/PHP

Tags: php, symfony, object

I send variables to my route via an ajax post. Based on the value of my `type` value I create a new Object, like this:

```
if($request->get('type') === 'HardwareType'){
    $e = new HardwareType();
}else if($request->get('type') === 'SetupType'){
    $e => new SetupType();
}else{
    new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

This gets out of hand quickly even with a `switch` I think its still "ugly". Is there any way I could do sth. like this:

```
$e = new $request->get('type')();
```

Any hint appreciated

EDIT I use the class(es) with this `use AppBundle\Entity\HardwareType;` etc.

Comment: Why not use a container, each class(or service, or whatever) can have an alias. Instead of doing `new HardwareType` you can use `$container->get('class_service_whatever_id`);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
$e = $request->get('type');
$class = new $e();
```

If you need you can add the path or the class like this:

```
$e = 'AppBundle\Entity\' . $request->get('type');
```

Obviously you need to add `use` at the begin of the file and you can check before the `new` if the class exist or not

Like this:

```
if (!class_exists($e)) {
   //exception
}
```

Comment: That has potential to fail without any checks

Comment: Hackers would love this in combination with a vulnerable Composer library

Comment: @Pete IKR? More strictness required!

Comment: Thanks for the concerns, it's an internal project only with no intention to ever go public. However, is there a safe approach? It worked btw. like a charm so I will accept this in any case! Thank you

Comment: use my approach below, it's better practice

Comment: could you let me know why? I don't see any improvements regarding security, did I miss sth?

Comment: @PrimuS Just make sure to validate the input and you will be fine.

Comment: My snippet defines an array of the get keys, and the allowed classes, so other classes can't be instantiated if they aren't in the $types definition

Comment: `$class = new ($request->get('type'))()` just allows a client to instantiate any class they want. This *could* be unsafe.

Comment: Take a look into the factory-pattern, maybe this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an associative array! Define the acceptable classes, so that other types of class you don't want to allow can't be instantiated!

Then just check the key is in the array, and if so create a new Whatever()!

```
$types = [
    'HardwareType' => HardwareType::class,
    'etc' => SomeOther::class
];

$getVar = $request->get('type');

// So all you need do is 
if (array_key_exists($getVar, $types)) {
    $e = new $types[$getVar]();
} else {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```